# Microsoft Column/Bar Chart is not working correctly if there is more than 9 bars/Columns in chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, bar-chart, rdlc

Edit :

I recognized that if there is less than or equal 9 bars, everything is working good. But if there is more than 9 bars in chart, labels started to print alternatively. Anyone has any workaround for this issue ?

Edit :
This is the same behavior with Winform Chart control. This is a bug in Microsoft Chart control.

I am working on C# 4.5 win form application with RDLC report. I have added a bar chart to my report. That looks like [image]

I set bar width = 10 in custom attributes. But there is no property to set distance between bars.

My problem is, if in report more bars will added then rdlc report shows x axis labels alternatively, please check the screen shot.[image: The yellow highlighted text is missing]

I want to fix this issue. It is happening because there is no much room to add more bars. But I don't know why labels are going to be hidden.

Comment: I dont know nothing about that library you are using here, but that is maybe a bug, or you need to find how to force to draw all labels, this is maybe happening because the code things there is not enough space to display them all, I am working on this https://github.com/beto-rodriguez, and you can configure that behavior easly, (actually bar chart should display all of them by default). sadly I only included one example for winforms. but I think it can help you.

Comment: I am using RDLC report designer in Winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the x-axis interval property to 1:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

In a column chart, the x-axis is the horizontal axis. In a bar chart, the x-axis is the vertical axis.